# How to concatenate fields in prisma using nestjs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I have a `firstname` and a `lastname` field. I'm writing a query to filter by a string. My query is something like this:

```
await this.prisma.person.findMany({
      where: {
        OR: [
          {
            firstname: {
              contains: filterString
            },
            lastname: {
              contains: filterString
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```

If I try to search for "John" then it works, but doesn't work for "john doe" even if I have a `firstname` as John and `lastname` as Doe. Is there any way to concatenate these two fields within the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the [Full Text Search](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#examples-43) feature which is currently in preview.

You can split your `filterString` by space, and pass all the elements in firstName and lastName clause. So considering element array, element[0] would have firstName and element[1] would have lastName.

```js
await this.prisma.person.findMany({
      where: {
        OR: [
          {
            firstname: {
              search: `${element[0]} | ${element[1]}`
            },
            lastname: {
              search: `${element[0]} | ${element[1]}`
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```